# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager for POST image not working into Xcode 6

Tags: afnetworking, xcode6.1, ios8.1

I am developing an application which required to upload image on server.For upload image I use following code.

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager1 = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager1.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager1.requestSerializer setValue:@"Content-Type" forHTTPHeaderField:@"text/html"];
manager1.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager1.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op= [manager1 POST:urlString parameters:Nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"photo" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg",timeStamp] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { }failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    [self dismissLoading];}];[op start];
```

My problem is that when I run same code from Xcode 5 into iPad 2 iOS 8.1, then It will work fine. But when I run same code from Xcode 6.1 into same iPad 2 iOS 8.1, It get request time out.

Please help..!

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago i also had the same problem with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager. I was not able to upload image on server with xcode 6. But when i resolve the warnings (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/0ae246896e2327a31d26dcb998375af8fe9209a2 ) then its working fine. Hope this will help you and others :)